# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' in beautiful soup

Tags: python, arrays, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've received a python web scraping project and when I am running this script in the range 0 to 100 it ran but when I increase the number to 120 or above it returns

> ```
> " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' "
> ```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as requests

arr=[]
arrUrl=[]
url = "https://www.exam-mate.com/topicalpastpapers/?cat=3&subject=16&years=&seasons=&chapter=&paper=2%20(Extended)&unit=&zone=&level=&offset=0"
ins = url.split("=")
eqn = "="
for s in range(120,240,20):
    ins[-1] = str(s)
    j = eqn.join(ins)
    arrUrl.append(j)
CountStr = 0
counting = 0
count = 0
while (count < len(arrUrl)):
    response = requests.urlopen(arrUrl[count])
    content = BeautifulSoup(response , "html.parser")
    for tit in content.find_all("div" , class_="question"):
    for title in tit.find_all("div"):
        AlasOfLast.append(title.string)

    while (CountStr < len(AlasOfLast)):
    if (AlasOfLast[CountStr] == None):
        del AlasOfLast[CountStr]
    CountStr += 1
    while (counting < len(AlasOfLast)):
    if (counting % 2 == 0):
        lenOfArr.append(AlasOfLast[counting])
    counting += 1
    AlasOfLast.clear()
    for n in range(len(lenOfArr)) :
    AlasOfLast.append(lenOfArr[n].strip())
    count += 1
print(AlasOfLast)
```

Comment: In Your code lenOfArr is getting stored as None.

That is why you are getting that error here.

Comment: Probably because the data being fetched became empty displaying None after the end.

Comment: but when i run the code in the range of 0 to 100 the code work??